# user_signed_in? is causing uninitialized constant error with Mongoid / Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I had some issues with a different ODM yesterday so I decided to take a look at Mongoid instead. The [wiki tutorial](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise/wiki/Tutorial) was pretty thorough, so it seemed like it was worth a shot. I went through the wiki article very carefully but may have missed something. Perhaps this is happening because I had a different ODM in the app yesterday. Anyway, now I'm getting an error:

`uninitialized constant User::Mongoid`

with this line of code (threw this in to confirm it was this method that was the issue):

```
<% if user_signed_in? -%>
5:     Hello user
6:     <% end -%>
```

user_signed_in is a Devise method. I suspect that Devise isn't actually loading but I'm not sure what to do next.

My gem file has `gem "devise", "1.5.0"` and I've run a `bundler install`, I can see that devise is getting installed. I've confirmed that my application controller exactly matches the app controller in the sample. My app starts with no issues when I run `rails server`. All the models in the app load correctly when I do `load 'app/models/user.rb'`. The file config/initializers/devise.rb has `require 'devise/orm/mongoid'`. I've verified that my User model exactly matches the one in the tutorial.

What should I look at next?

**Update**: This was fixed, but I'm still missing how. I started the app on a new port. That's all it took. I was making changes to my index.html.erb and seeing those changes in the error that I was getting so I know the new code was being seen. But when I started the app on a new port the error went away. Perhaps there's some sort of 'hard recompile' in rails that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, confirm that the error is still happening after you fully restart your rails instance.

I suppose that in the User model you have something like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  devise :database_authenticatable, ...
end
```

Check in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/mongoid'
```

Also check that devise gem is under mongoid gem in Gemfile:

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.3.2"
gem "bson_ext"
gem "devise", "~> 1.4.9"
```

Comment: Check, check and pretty close. The gemfile didn't match that exactly -- slightly different version and order. Changing it to match yours didn't fix it.

Comment: I forgot to add `restart application`. BTW what kind of app server do you use: webrick, unicorn, ...?

Comment: Mongrel. I didn't know about the restart command, I'll try that in the future.

Comment: It's not a command. I meant that you had to restart application server to initialize new settings.